# Will reboot without CMOS battery cause BIOS reset? (If laptop is plugged in)

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery, cmos

I have an odd situation, where my CMOS battery case has broken, so the battery is fine, but it gets disloged, and my computer doesn't boot with default BIOS Settings. *Non-UEFI*. So far I have managed to hold the CMOS in place and then change BIOS settings and reboot. Once I'm in the OS, I place the laptop back down regularly.

**Can I reboot the Laptop without the CMOS (same as it being "dislodged") without resetting the BIOS, if the unit is plugged in?**

Comment: This post has been downvoted to no end, but I stand by what I experienced. I WAS able to reboot without resetting BIOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have rebooted, powered off, and been able to power on successfully. The only time I lost BIOS settings was when I lost power and my laptop drained its battery. I have even disconnected power and powered off and not lost power, because the laptop battery had power.

Answer (score -2):

You can probably reboot without issue, but a complete power down, will most definitely reset the clock, and cause boot issues - maybe even clear your bios settings.

You should get this fixed, or replace the MoBo ASAP.

Comment: Better description and more clarity would probably be more relevant in the question, than the answer. Your comments and questions seem to contradict each other slightly.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can, but without the CMOS battery the BIOS settings are gone, and the laptop will boot with the default BIOS, and as described on the question, with expected boot issues.

Comment: Don't you think it's a little odd, we both got down voted twice... on a question with zero up votes or favorites?

Comment: Yes, but due to the general regulations of this site for unmoderated voting, we only have to accept this ... Have been facing few times somehow maybe unfair downvotes, right or no, there is nothing to do. OK, my answer was based on some cases during years maybe mainly for desktops without the actual loadable big battery, so this laptop case seems to be nowadays somehow different ...

Comment: Somebody else downvoted you both immediately and i downvoted you after concluding that your answers were wrong. If laptop has power but no CMOS i do NOT lose settings in bios upon reboot.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers OK, ok, accepted ... I may not have been facing just such case during some time ...

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Restart, and power off, are not the same thing, and from your comments, it does not seem, that you are being completely truthful, about what you are actually doing. Both of our answers are valid, in real world situations, and much closer to how computers really work, than your suggested experience.